# Codecademy is giving me a hard time, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours); {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return("You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
};
    else (numHours => 8) {
        return("Get some more shut eye!");
}
sleepCheck(10);
```

It is telling me to:

1. Write a function named sleepCheck that takes the parameter numHours
2. Inside the function, write an if statement where if the number of hours of sleep is greater than or equal to 8, the computer will return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";.
3. Otherwise (else) if the number of hours of sleep is less than 8, have the computer return "Get some more shut eye!";

Then call the function with different hours of sleep

1. Call the function with 10 hours of sleep, like this: sleepCheck(10);
2. Call the function with 5 hours of sleep.
3. Call the function with 8 hours of sleep.

PS: I am a complete coding amateur, I just started Javascript two days ago.

Comment: return isn't a `function`, just try `return 'string';`

Comment: syntax error is here: `function(numHours);` should just be `function(numHours){`

Comment: also after the closing bracket for your if block. Quick note that will save you lots DON'T put semi-colons after any bracket. Yes yes it's allowed but you are just going to run into troubles if you just go throwing semi's around like candy

Comment: I still get an unexpected token error.

Comment: if you look at the line of the syntax error your console tools will generally point you where your unexpected token error is. in this case it's that extra `;` after the closing `}`.

Comment: `var sleepCheck = function(numHours); ` The error comes from this semicolon. You can't declare a function like that.

Comment: Some people say programming books are unnecessary these days. But I suggest getting something appropriate with good reviews on Amazon or somehting. The thing about a book is it will take you systematically through stuff in quite a bit of depth and you can thumb through it easily. You'll probably make much quicker progress getting going.

Comment: Now you just need to add a last `}`, to close the function bracket out before you try to call the function. Line your brackets up with the block they define and that will help you see these types of errors in the future

Comment: As an aside: you shouldn't edit your question with code changes. It makes your question and the answers useless to anyone else.

Comment: Rolled back as per what Collin said. Leave the question and the original code as is; otherwise anyone else looking at this will not understand what all the hubbub was about.

Answer (score 3):

Change `else (numHours => 8)` to just `else`.

You're also missing some braces.

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
    if (numHours >= 8) {
        return("You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!");
    } else (numHours => 8) {
        return("Get some more shut eye!"); 
    }
};
sleepCheck(10);
sleepCheck(8);
sleepCheck(5);
```

Notice how I matched my braces by having the closing brace at the same column as the statement with its corresponding opening brace.

If you think about it, this makes more sense anyway. `else` wouldn't make sense with a condition. It's a catch all. Its condition is everything else not caught by the `if` and `else if` blocks before it.

Comment: It still gives me "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Comment: @Just_A_Mainer Did you remove the curly brace as well? It should look like `else {`

Comment: you still have the OP's extra semi after the `function(numHours);`

Comment: @Paul Richter Yeah, it still gives me the same error though.

Comment: @Just_A_Mainer, I see you're a new user. If you think this answers your question to your satisfaction, don't forget to click the accept button (check mark). Of course, if you want to wait to see if you get a better answer, that is your right.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var sleepCheck= function(numHours){
    var sleepCheck = prompt("How much did you sleep");
     if(numHours>=8){
        return"You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
    }
    else (numHours<= 8);{
        return "Get some more shut eye!";
    }
};
sleepCheck(10);
```